# Yii framework, CException Property "Image.path" is read only

Tags: file-upload, yii

I'm trying to save a CUploadedFile object in local folder, I am using img module for yii. I get this error:

```
CException Property "Image.path" is read only.
```

In Stack trace it shows that this is causing the error:

```
CActiveRecord->__set("path", "show_gallery"):

public function save($file,$name=null,$path=null)
{
 ....
if($path!==null)
      $image->path=trim($path,'/');
 ...
```

and it is provoked by:

```
ImgManager->save(CUploadedFile, "some_name", "show_gallery"):

Yii::app()->image->save($modelPhoto->content,'some_name','show_gallery');
```

Comment: Check the permissions on the folder.

Comment: I gave 777 permission to the folder and subforders, but still I get the same error

Comment: In that case, make sure that you give the full path to the `save` method, and not just a file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates that the property of the class Image is read-only, which also means there is no setter method for that property called path. It has nothing to do with the filesystem, but more with the code.

Are you using a 3rd party extension? Can you provide the whole Image model code?

Comment: Yes I was using img module. inside the model I defined a setter method and used the method to set the value, instead of doing it directly...